# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am trying to use the [canusb package](https://github.com/spiralray/canusb) on ROS Noetic (installed on Raspberry PI OS x64) but the problem is this package is written on python2 but Noetic uses python3 so there are some incompatibilities.

When I am trying to run the package the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/canusb/script/canusb.py", line 191, in <module>
    can.init()
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/canusb/script/canusb.py", line 57, in init
    line = self.readline()
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/canusb/script/canusb.py", line 51, in readline
    ret += c
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

The code lines on the package are:

```
def readline(self):
            """
            Overrides io.RawIOBase.readline which cannot handle with '\r' delimiters
            """
            ret = ''
            while True:
                c = self.read(1)
                if c == '':
                    return ret
                elif c == '\r':
                    if ret == 'z' or ret == 'Z':
                        self.status = 0
                    return ret + c
                elif c == chr(7):
                    self.status = -1
                    return c
                else:
                    ret += c
```

What can I change to fix the problem up?

Thnaks in advance.

Best regards.
Alessandro

EDIT

Appear the following errors:`[ERROR][]: Disable timestamp: Failed!` and `[ERROR][]: Disable baudrate: Failed!`.
I post the links of the original and the modified code below.

[Original](https://universidaddealcala-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/alessandro_melino_edu_uah_es/ETm182XsxvRMie32TkvqIS8B7az59REQf71I3H7DdOv-kQ?e=JEvzt7)

[Modified](https://universidaddealcala-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/alessandro_melino_edu_uah_es/EdY3jAIgDu9Lm5xWtSS69AsBEX89ZcX1uzbLvLuKL7MWbQ?e=ed8EYw)

I hope with this anyone can help me.
Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361381/typeerror:-can-only-concatenate-str-(not-%22bytes%22)-to-str/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-09-13**:
As you've found Python 3 treats this differently than Python 2 and 3.25 minutes with google gave me a full background on the issue and several ways to solve your particular question. But given what I just found on google, I suspect any changes you make on this bit of code may propagate throughout the node and lead you down a path of self destruction. If you need to use nodes written in Python 2 and you're not a Python programmer, probably want to consider using earlier version of ROS that uses Python2.

https://www.google.com/search?q=python+cast+byte+to+string&oq=python+cast+byte+to+string&aqs=chrome..69i57.8663j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-09-15**:
Effectively I am not a python programmer so I am a bit lost. I try changing code googling and porting code from python2 to 3 as you said, and now I have some big problems (see the edit in question).
The problem of use other version od ROS is that in RPI4 with debian almost nothing doesnt work.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-09-15**:
RPi4 with Ubuntu 18 and ROS Melodic seem to work fine. Melodic runs Python 2.
https://answers.ros.org/question/359358/ros-kinetic-on-raspberry-pi-4/?comment=359485#post-id-359485

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-09-15**:
I have alredy tried Ubuntu 18 (Server) on RPI4 and it was so slow. I don't know the reason but it was very difficult to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved creating a script from scratch.

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2021-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0